# Spock Spy/Mock not registering the invocations

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

I have a method in my test class that just calls two other methods. I am trying to write a test that checks that those two methods are actually invoced, but no invocations are registered. 
Java code I'm testing:

```
    public void populateEdgeInfo(Map<Actor, SchedulableNode> knownNodes) {
        populateDestinationInfo(knownNodes);
        populateSourceInfo(knownNodes);
    }
```

My test code:

```
def "Populating edge info means both source and destination information will be populated" () {
    given:
    actor.getDstChannels() >> []
    actor.getSrcChannels() >> []
    SchedulableNode schedulable = Spy(SchedulableNode, constructorArgs: [actor])

    when:
    schedulable.populateEdgeInfo([:])

    then:
    1 * schedulable.populateDestinationInfo(_)
    1 * schedulable.populateSourceInfo(_)
}
```

The only thing registered is the call to populateEdgeInfo. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? Also tried using Mock instead of Spy to no avail.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you seem to be over-specifying your test - why would you want to check those class-internal interactions? - the basic use case with the spy looks okay. Would you mind showing more of your class under test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your sparse information and found no problems in your test:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60926015;

import java.util.List;

public class Actor {
  public List getDstChannels() {
    return null;
  }

  public List getSrcChannels() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60926015;

import java.util.Map;

public class SchedulableNode {
  private Actor actor;

  public SchedulableNode(Actor actor) {
    this.actor = actor;
  }

  public void populateEdgeInfo(Map<Actor, SchedulableNode> knownNodes) {
    populateDestinationInfo(knownNodes);
    populateSourceInfo(knownNodes);
  }

  public void populateDestinationInfo(Map<Actor, SchedulableNode> knownNodes) {}

  public void populateSourceInfo(Map<Actor, SchedulableNode> knownNodes) {}
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q60926015

import spock.lang.Specification

class SchedulableNodeTest extends Specification {
  def actor = Mock(Actor)

  def "Populating edge info means both source and destination information will be populated"() {
    given:
    actor.getDstChannels() >> []
    actor.getSrcChannels() >> []
    SchedulableNode schedulable = Spy(SchedulableNode, constructorArgs: [actor])

    when:
    schedulable.populateEdgeInfo([:])

    then:
    1 * schedulable.populateDestinationInfo(_)
    1 * schedulable.populateSourceInfo(_)
  }
}
```

That means that your code must be different from mine. **My guess is that both `populate*` methods are `private` in your class,** which makes it impossible to mock them because mocks use dynamic proxies and the latter are sub-classes technically. Sub-classes do not see private super-class methods, though, thus a dynamic proxy cannot intercept (calls to) them.

Possible solutions:

- Stop over-specifying your tests and testing internal interactions. It makes the test brittle and you have to refactor it often if you also refactor the class under test.
- Make the `populate*` methods protected or package-scoped if public is not right. Then you can stub them and check interactions on them.

Comment: You are correct, those methods were private. Thank you, I understand now! The reason for adding the test was to not have the red in the coverage for that method because my understanding was that public methods not being covered by tests is bad practice.

Comment: I didn't say you should not test your public methods. I even go as far as saying you should completely cover all private methods via testing the public ones. If you cannot, something is wrong with your application design. What I said was that there is no need for _interaction testing_, i.e. for doing checks that private methods are being called like `1 * myMock.myMethod(_)`. You see that in the coverage report.